# Surd inside Surd equality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I was trying a problem where I got the following surd as my answer:

$$ {\sqrt{6 - 2 \sqrt{5} }\over 4} \approx 0.309016.... $$

The answer listed was:

$$ {\sqrt{5} - 1 \over 4} \approx 0.309016....  $$

Is there a simple way that you could get to the second expression from the first?

Comment: Yes : note that $(\sqrt 5 - 1)^2 = 6 - 2 \sqrt 5$, which you can verify by explicit multiplication, or the square of sum formula. So the left hand side of both expressions are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, solve $\,0=16x^4-12x^2+1=(4x^2+2x-1)(4x^2-2x-1)\,$ in two different ways.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you assume that you can write $\sqrt{6-2\sqrt5} = \sqrt a - \sqrt b$ for some rational numbers $a$ and $b$. Squaring both sides will give you $6-2\sqrt5 = a+b-2\sqrt{ab}$, and so
\begin{align*}
6 &= a+b \\
\sqrt{5} &= \sqrt{ab}
\end{align*}
So we want $ab=5$ and $a+b=6$. An obvious solution is, indeed, $a=5$ and $b=1$. (Taking $a=1$ and $b=5$ gives a negative result for $\sqrt a-\sqrt b$.)

Comment: Ahh thank you kindly :) That really should have been obvious to me! Thanks for your help Ted! - I need to wait 7 minutes to accept this

Comment: No problem. One can easily derive from this a necessary and sufficient condition in general for there to be a solution with $a$ and $b$ rational. :)

Answer (score 2):

If we square  $$\sqrt{6 - 2 \sqrt{5} }$$ We get $$6- 2 \sqrt{5}=(\sqrt 5 -1)^2$$

Thus $$\sqrt{6 - 2 \sqrt{5} } = \sqrt 5 -1$$